# Computer Archiecture - Memory Hierarchy

Tags: memory, architecture, hierarchy

So I have a question here, I'm confused on what to do. I will write the question and how I interpret it:

The following memory addresses are used consecutively by a running program (from left to right, shown in
decimal). Note that the followings are memory address not block number:
100, 40, 360, 116, 224, 18, 440, 100, 1024, 44, 168, 40, 104

In each of the following cache structures, compute the number of hits, misses and the final values
stored in each cache location (show finally which block of memory is in each cache block). Each
word is 4-bytes and the memory size is 2Kbyte
(a) Direct-mapped cache with eight-word blocks and a total size of cache is 32 words of data

There are more parts to the question however I just need help to get it started and I can do the rest myself. So basically we are given the memory addresses. Our cache size is 32 words and 8 words/block hence there are 4 blocks in the cache. How I don't understand what to do with the memory size being 2kbyte? Do I just divide by 4 to get the number of blocks in the memory? Or do I have to divide the memory address by 4?

Answer (score 0):

> How I don't understand what to do with the memory size being 2kbyte?

The memory size is irrelevant to this part of the problem.

You can subdivide memory into blocks.  Each cache block is 8 words (32 bytes).  You can cache 32 words, which is a round-about way of saying 4 blocks.

Write the address range next to each block.  Then, start playing CPU and use the listed memory addresses, tracking which block you hit and whether that block should be in cache or not.

Comment: So basically I would just do 100 mod 4 = 0 means write to block 0 of cache. Then I take the next address and repeat and write to corresponding block of cache?

Comment: No, I believe the correct way to view it is addresses 0-31 are the first block of memory, addresses 32-63 are the second block of memory, etc.  When you touch a block of memory, it is placed in the cache.  If this happens while the cache is full, a different block is removed from the cache (presumably the least recently used one).

Comment: Oh ok, so let's say the memory address is 100, that falls in between 96-127 which is block 4 of memory. So I take block 4 mod 4 which is 0 and then place in block 0 of cache (assuming we are using direct mapping)

Comment: I'm not sure what your caching algorithm is supposed to be.  A real CPU would not just use modulo to assign a memory address to a cache block, it would try to be intelligent about keeping pages in cache that are frequently accessed.  At the very least, a real CPU would use a LRU (least recently used) algorithm to throw things out of cache.  Perhaps for this purpose you are supposed to use a simpler algorithm; I'm not sure.

Comment: We were to use direct mapping to fill the cache. The memory addresses were given and we were only told cache has a total size of 32 words and each block is 8 words. We werent given very clear instructions but using the modulo express I got a miss in every case...